# GLFW window not rendering close button?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

My GLFW window renders but the title bar does not render like it does in the tutorial I am following.
I am using fedora on wayland.
Here is the code :

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void) {
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit()) return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
        glEnd();

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

the output is here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUwOC.jpg

Comment: Perhaps on Wayland you need to explicitly add window decorations using `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, 1)` before creating the window?

Comment: I will try that

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Is this a wayland problem

Comment: Could be a Wayland specific problem, the code couldn't be any simpler and it looks fine to me.  Maybe try forums specific to that OS to see if it's a known issue.

Comment: No this is not a OS specific issue. According to some github bug report it should have been fixed

Comment: The code in the question works perfectly fine for me on Windows 10. So it's either an OS problem or a problem of your specific machine.

Comment: I think i will have to use some other operating system

Comment: I found that the problem is wayland specific, and so switched to xorg and it worked